# How to replicate a sliding search bar similar to the one on Petfinder

Tags: javascript, css

I try to create something similar to Petfinder search menu.

1. The problem I'm stuck with is that I can't figure out how to make a slide always appear just before the button(only covering it and not propogate to its borders when I change the size of the screen). When the slide search meets the 'heart' element it should act like it hits a wall and not going through it. So the search menu should appear before the button and replacing the previous content from the left side. I tried many options, included hiding this menu by setting width to 0 vw and heigt to 0 vh and positioning it fixed but it wasn't the case. Look at this picture. When I click the search button the menu appears but how to make it appear right from the button and not from the right edge of the screen as it does now? (see the code below)
2. The second question is how to incorporate this search to a css flow so it all will act as a flex element as a whole when the size of the screen changes? Because right now this slide not shrink when I change width of the screen.
   But my search always gets one width. It gets confusing when the size of the screen gets smaller. It results in elements overlaying one another.

[image: my case]

```js
const slide = document.getElementById('slide');
let open = true;

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
  if (open) {
   slide.classList.add('show')
}
})
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #EEE;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.first,
.second,
.third {
  padding: 30px;
}

.first {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex-basis: 120px;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1
}

.third {
  background-color: #56D7F7;
  flex-grow: 1
}

.btn {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background-color: #FFE689;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform .3s
              cubic-bezier(0, .52, 0, 1);
}

.show {
   transform: translateX(80%);
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='first'>1</div>
   <div class='second'>2</div>
   <div id='btn' class='btn'>Button</div>
   <div class='third'>3</div>
</div>
  <div id='slide' class='slide'>
      Hello 
</div>
```

[image: How It should be]

The picture above shows how it should look like.
The code here is just for the sake of example, I am doing it on React but the problem is clear.

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the petfinder scroll? This way we have a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well other than inspecting the elements on petfinder's website and deconstructing their styles, this is a rough version that I think performs as you are specifying.

```js
const searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-bar');
const openBtn = document.querySelector('#open-btn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('#close-btn');
const brand = document.querySelector('#brand');

openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleSlider() );
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleSlider() );

function toggleSlider(){
  searchBar.classList.toggle('open');
  brand.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.example{
  max-width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.example .btns{
  width:100px;
}

.slide-area{
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  position: relative;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.brand{
  z-index:100;
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
.brand.open{
  color:white;
}

.search-bar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:purple;
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition:all 1s ease;
  
}

.search-bar form{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-content:center;
}
.search-bar input[type="text"]{
  margin-left:10px;
}

.search-bar.open{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<header class="example">
  <div class="slide-area">
    <div id="brand" class="brand">Petfinder</div>
    <nav>Menu Stuff</nav>
    <button id="open-btn">Search</button>
    <div id="search-bar" class="search-bar">
      <label>Search:</label>
      <form>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="submit" value="search"/>
      </form>
      <button id="close-btn">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">Heart</div>
  <div class="btns">Sign up</div>
  <div class="btns">Log in</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I asked for!